# "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable" error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a ticketing system for a Discord bot and I'm getting an error when the bot tries to open a channel for support.

This is the error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/cogs/ticket.py", line 67, in on_raw_reaction_add
    if user_channel_id in items:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

and this is the snippet of code where the error is coming from:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        if payload.member.id != self.bot.user.id:
            with open('db/data.json', 'r') as file:
                ticket_data = json.load(file)

            channel_id = list(ticket_data.values())
            user_channel_id = payload.channel_id

            for items in channel_id:
                if user_channel_id in items:
                    # Get guild and roles
                    find_guild = discord.utils.find(lambda guild: guild.id == payload.guild_id, self.bot.guilds)
                    guild_roles = discord.utils.get(find_guild.roles, name=f'{payload.member.name}')
```

Comment: the variable `items` is actually the `channel_id` therefore the `in` operator won't work

Comment: does `items` contain an integer? `if something in somelist` would only work in somelist is an iterable, i.e. list, tuple, etc.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve]. The code could probably be trimmed down to be minimal, and we do not know what `items` or `channel_id` are. See [ask] for more information

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message carefully as well as the line that it is pointing to. It is actually quite explicit.
Your variable `channel_id` is a list of integers, so when your iterate over them the variable `items` is an integer, on which you cannot iterate (as an integer cannot be iterated).

You can probably try this:

```py
channel_ids = list(ticket_data.values())
user_channel_id = payload.channel_id
if user_channel_id in channel_ids:
    # Get guild and roles
    find_guild = discord.utils.find(lambda guild: guild.id == payload.guild_id, self.bot.guilds)
    guild_roles = discord.utils.get(find_guild.roles, name=f'{payload.member.name}')
```

note the use of `'s'` where variables point to lists. It will make your code more readable/understandable.